# Determining if all items in a range are equal to a specific value

Tags: python-3.x, list, range, tic-tac-toe

This question is related to the tic tac toe problem using python: Let's say I have a list - `my_list = ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', '-', 'O', 'X', 'X']`. I want to determine if all the items in `range(0, 2) or range(3, 5) or range(6, 8) == X` So far I have tried the following, but get a syntax error:

```
my_list = ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', '-', 'O', 'X', 'X']

for i in range(0, 3):
    if all(board[i]) == 'X':
        print('X is the winner')
    elif all(board[i]) == 'Y':
        print('Y is the winner')
```

The problem really stems from setting up the range on the second line, but I also feel I am not using the `all` function correctly. Can you shed light my mistake here? Side note: I also want to check to see if index `items[0, 3, 6]`, `[1, 4, 7]`, and `[2, 5, 8]`-the "columns" as well as the diagonals index`[0, 4, 8]` and `[6, 4, 2]` are all of a specific value.

Comment: `range(0, 1, 2)` doesn't consist of the numbers 0, 1, and 2. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range).

Comment: Edited the range. Sorry, I'm new to Python and got it confused.

Comment: Add a `print(I) in the loop`. This should help to see that this won't work.

Comment: OK, I edited again to use `if all(board[i]) == 'X': print('X is the winner')` It runs but doesn't print the statement. Am I using `all` incorrectly?

Comment: @jcbridwe `if all(cell == 'X' for cell in board): ...`. The `all` and `any` functions check the truthiness of an iterable.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing the winner indices explicitly works:

```
my_list = ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', '-', 'O', 'X', 'X']

winner_indices = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],
                  [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],
                  [0, 4, 8], [6, 4, 2]]

no_winner = True
for indices in winner_indices:
    selected = [my_list[index] for index in indices]
    for party in ['X', 'O']:
        if all(item == party for item in selected):
            print('{} is the winner'.format(party))
            no_winner = False
if no_winner:
    print('nobody wins')
```

Answer (score -1):

You are not considering all winning combinations when deciding the winner.
The approach I am going to use can be used to generate winning combination grid in a generic way. That can help even if you wish to scale.

My solution uses [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) package. Install it if you don't already have.

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

#Define size of your grid
n_dim = 3

#Input list from players
my_list = ['X', 'O', 'X', 'O', 'X', '-', 'O', 'X', 'X']

#Generate a n_dim*n_dim grid and reshape it in rows and columns
grid = np.arange(n_dim*n_dim).reshape(n_dim, n_dim)

#Get all rows and columns out from the grid as they all are winning combinations
grid_l = list(chain.from_iterable((grid[i].tolist(), grid[:,i].tolist()) for i in range(n_dim)))

#Get the forward diagonal
grid_l.append(grid.diagonal().tolist())

#Get reverse diagonal
grid_l.append(np.diag(np.fliplr(grid)).tolist())

#Check if any player's combination matches with any winning combination
result = [i for i in grid_l if all(my_list[k] == 'X'  for k in i) or all(my_list[k] == 'O' for k in i)]
#result [[0,4,8]]
```